# How to retrieve MAC id from ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, networking

I want to retrieve MAC ID of all users who are visiting to my website. How can I do this ?

Is it possible to retrieve MAC ID on Web

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, this is not possible.  IIS doesn't log it, and the best thing you can get is the IP address of the user.

The MAC is sent at the network level, so there is a possibility that you could insert a proxy between the client & the IIS server that you may be able to capture this, but not out of the box with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "MAC" addresses are reported by most browsers. It's not in any of the http headers. I imagine you'd have deploy a client-side application which would query the network adaptor that was being used to connect to the internet for it's MAC address, and then send that.

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/GetMacAddress.htm

Or use a java applet: http://rizwanshah.blogspot.com/2009/04/restrict-web-page-access-based-on-mac.html